# Netbeans Default Options, startng jvm with more memory

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, out-of-memory

I am getting OutOfMemoryException. I increased memory of jvm  in netbeans by Project->Properties->Run->VM Options to -Xms1600M -Xmx1600M.

I am running 32-bit java, on windows 7 4GB RAM JDK version 1.7 Netbeans Version 7.0.1

But when i run,

```
System.out.println("MaxMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/1024);
System.out.println("FeeMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024/1024);
System.out.println("TotalMemory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024/1024);
```

I get

`MaxMemory: 247
FeeMemory: 14
TotalMemory: 15`

I tried to change netbeans_default_options by changinf netbeans.conf file.

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

to

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xmx1800m -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

But it gives me JVM creation failed error.

**EDITED**

As suggested change made:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xmx1400m -J-Xms1400m -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

Still getting JVM Creation failed error

Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem with the Netbeans config is that it may require the `-J-Xms` value as well

Comment: `1800m` is too much for a 32bit JVM. Try lowering that to `1400m`

Comment: Please refer to the edit above

Comment: I'd start by removing the `-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` options, as they don't to appear in the original config. Let's start with the memory options only...

Comment: not working that way either. `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xmx1400m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"` is the options now. Included them because it was suggested in the config file comments that if I wanted to include -Xmx explicitly, i may want to include those as well

Comment: Try a little lower, something like `-J-Xmx512m -J-Xms32m` ??

Comment: Also, from the Netbeans site, you might like to try a restart...don't ask me, just reporting back my findings

Comment: I am able to start netbeans without any error after lowering the value, but still running `OutOfMemory`. Also, `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1024/1024` is giving me 247 and `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024/1024` is giving 13. I have restarted IDE many every time i made a change. Or are you talking about restarting my system. Would it be a good idea to restart my system everytime I made a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled everything(java and netbeans) and reinstalled everything(java and netbeans). It is still not able to assign -Xmx1400m but assigns -Xmx1000m and works well. Thank you everyone for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not so sure but as what i've known, if you are running on a 32 bit environment, you cannot assign more than 1GB of memory to the jvm.

for more information refer to this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html